# Using CSS variable to define -webkit-background-clip property doesn't work on Chrome

Tags: css, background, css-variables, vendor-prefix

It's "well known" that you can use a CSS variable to simplify writing properties that require browser-specific vendor prefixes. (See Lea Verou, "[Autoprefixing, with CSS variables!](http://lea.verou.me/2016/09/autoprefixing-with-css-variables/)".) For example,

```
* {
  --clip-path: initial ;
  -webkit-clip-path: var( --clip-path ) ;
  clip-path: var( --clip-path ) ;
}
.maximalCircle {
  --clip-path: circle(50%);
}
```

In this example,

- Setting `--clip-path:initial;` cancels inheritance so an element will have a `clip-path` value other than `initial` (which equals `border-box`) only if `--clip-path` is defined within that element.
- `--clip-path: circle(50%);` effectively sets the value for both the vanilla `clip-path` and the WebKit-specific `-webkit-clip-path` properties.

You can see this in action at [this Pen](https://codepen.io/jimratliff/pen/wLyxBP).

I'm failing, however, in using CSS variables to simplify a different property: the `-webkit-background-clip` property: if I assign a CSS variable `--clip-path:text;` as the value of the `-webkit-background-clip` property, (a) Safari (and Firefox) like it fine but (b) Chrome doesn't understand it (i.e., the computed value in Chrome is `background-clip: border-box`, which is the default value).

[In all these tests, I'm using Safari 12.1.1, Firefox Quantum 67.0.4, Firefox Developer Edition 68.0b12, and Chrome 75.0.3770.100.]

Cliff Notes for below minimum working example: A `<div class="text-masked-gradient">` contains a text string, which sits on a gradient background. The CSS `background-clip:text` (and/or `-webkit-background-clip:text`) property should cause the background to show through only the text itself. The image below shows (a) what it looks like when it works (L) and (b) when it doesn't (R).

[image]

My HTML markup:

```
<div class="text-masked-gradient">
  YELP
</div>
```

Full CSS is below. This code also exists at [this Pen](https://codepen.io/jimratliff/pen/b5df16e7c134933a44048467e925076a). (I consider many more scenarios, for diagnostic purposes, at [this other Pen](https://codepen.io/jimratliff/pen/35be3a77346c801181eb15a662855815).)

The full CSS:

```
.text-masked-gradient {
  --background-clip: text ;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: var( --background-clip );

  height: 150px ;
  width: 300px ;
  outline: solid black ;
  margin: 50px ;
  font-size: 7em ;
  text-align: center ;
  font-weight: 700 ;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at top left,red,chartreuse);
}
```

This renders correctly in:

- Safari
- Firefox Quantum
- Firefox Developers Edition

but not in

- Chrome (where the entire rectangle is the gradient, with no text).

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a Chrome bug related to CSS variables and the `-webkit-background-clip` property?

(This example works fine in all these browsers, including Chrome, if you use `-webkit-background-clip:text` rather than `webkit-background-clip:var(--background-clip)`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lea Verou has confirmed that this is a Chrome bug. She created this [reduced test case](http://dabblet.com/gist/642b562f0246d138b7db5dfeb432d109), which fails when viewed with Chrome. She filed this bug report: [Issue 980439](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=980439).

On top of that, there's a WebKit bug (thus affecting both Safari and Chrome) when you try to define the `background-clip` property with a CSS variable, e.g., `background-clip:--a`, where the CSS variable is `text`. This causes both Chrome and Safari to ignore a valid `-webkit-background-clip:text` rule. See [Bug 199410 - `background-clip:var(--a)` invalidates `-webkit-background-clip:text` when `--a:text`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199410).

Due to both of these bugs, the `background-clip` property isn't at this time a good candidate for using CSS variables to simplify vendor prefixes.